# How to use Hibernate in a Java program to update a value in column?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a simple web app that checks the status of a column,it can either be Active (value 1) or Obsolete (value2).

If it's Active, it will be given an option to edit it. Then if it's obsolete, it will be given an option to do so. The problem is when I retrieve an obsolete document, it will still be given an option to edit. So I was thinking of updating manually the status column in my table right before displaying the obsolete document so it actually disable the ability to edit.

I know it will work because I directly changed the value in the column itself but of course I'll need to implement the logic in code itself.

This is a snippet of File.java:

```
private EntityManager em;

     public Node get_folder(long fileID) {
            try {
                List resList = nodeFacade.list_parent(fileID, LinkType.FILE);


                List resList1 = nodeFacade.list_parent(fileID, LinkType.VER_LINKS);

                if (resList == null) {
                    throw new Exception("failed to get folder of a file." + nodeFacade.getMsg());
                }

                if (resList.size() > 1) {
                    throw new Exception("one file cannot be attached to more than one folder(s).");
                }

                //fixed bugs: modified here to display different version
                if(resList1.size()==1){
                    Fmedia fmedia = new Fmedia(fileID);
                    fmedia.setFstatus(2);

     /// This section where I expect the status to be changed from 1 to 2

                    return (Node) resList1.get(0);
                }

                return (Node) resList.get(0);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                msg = CoreUtil.wrapMsg(CoreUtil.FUNC_ERROR,
                        this.getClass().getName(), "get_folder", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Given that logic, it should change the existing value from 1 to 2 right before displaying the document so it's able to disable the edit. Problem is it doesn't seem to update anything in the table, nothing changes and I don't know why. Ran a debug and it does pass in the correct ID but it doesn't change/update the status column.

Fmedia.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "fmedia")
public class Fmedia implements Serializable {
 @Column(name = "FSTATUS")
    private int fstatus;

  public int getFstatus() {
        return fstatus;
    }

    public void setFstatus(int fstatus) {
        this.fstatus = fstatus;
    }
```

It's using Hibernate to insert or update the table but adding `em.persist(fmedia)` does not help and gives more error. Also, I can't use `.save` for JPA because my project is running on JAVA 7.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I don't understand; you exit what status to change? You create a new Fmedia but I don't see where you do anything with it.

Comment: I'm trying to change/update the column `fstatus` in table fmedia.The existing value of the obsolete document is 1,hence it allows to edit. So by changing it to 2, the ability to edit is removed. That's what I need to achieve.

Comment: Can you paste stacktrace?

Comment: @Andronicus Okay. Depends stacktrack when I use persist, or refresh?

Comment: From your description I'm not sure what your problem is, I just need clarification. Also could you clear the snippet a bit (too many newlines and indentations)?

Comment: @Andronicus Basically, I need to update the value in table column (fstatus) to 2 so it's able to hide the edit button. As for stacktrace, it just says null pointer exception.

Comment: There is nothing about NullPointerException in your question... Seems to me like you should focus on one error at the time

Comment: I posted another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54685161/jsp-how-to-hide-or-disable-a-button-from-after-clicking-from-drop-down-list  which is related to this issue,with a screenshot so it's easier you can read this thread